# Why Google Play store app doesn't show the preview video

Tags: android, youtube, google-play, google-play-console, applocker

I can see the preview video of this app [App Locker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.tuantv.android.applocker) on Google Play store website, but can't see it on Google Play store app.
Do you know why?

The video URL is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sWF9jMJpTMY

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is from your device, it is visible on devices

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Go to your android settings under YouTube you clear your cache and data then go in playstore it will play the app previews